# Numpy: How to put ones in a 2d array of zeros, using the values of a 1d array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy.array of (n x 10) with zeros and also I have another numpy.array of n with numbers between 0 and 9.

I would like to put ones in the 2 dimensions array according to the number that appears in the 1 dimension array. eg

```
a = [1,4,8]
b = [[0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
     [0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0],
     [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0]]
```

I can do this with loops but I think it would be really slow with a big dataset (what I will use). I tried the following but I am told that I am writing an invalid sintax. Does anyone know what I am missing here?

```
[c_[row][col]=1 for row,col in enumerate(c)]
```

Thanks

Comment: Do : `b[np.arange(3), a] = 1`.

Comment: Thanks @Divakar. That solved the problem